# MYSQL - Character string length 20, field accepts varchar(15), no error generated?

Tags: mysql, debugging, varchar

I'm building a PHP/HTML front end to a MySQL database.

The table I'm attempting to work with defined with a column that is varchar(15).  I can run (without error) an insert statement with a character string that is 20 characters long.  The resulting record's column is truncated to 15 characters, but no error is generated.

How do I get this to generate an error?

I know that the interface can do the error checking, but I want to know how to get the database to reject the data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's fairly forgiving and will try to gracefully accept anything you pass it as best you can, silently converting/truncating/nulling if need be.

Since you don't want that, you need to enable the various "strict" mode options: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to know!  I just hadn't come across "strict" before.  Much appreciated!